# Как правильно вызвать нативную камеру из Delphi приложения на Андроид?

Tags: android, delphi, камера, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

Использую Delphi 10.3 Community Edition для написания простого Android приложения и пробую в нем вызвать нативную камеру, но получаю ошибку.

Следую официальному [гайду](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Taking_and_Sharing_a_Picture_(iOS_and_Android)):

> On the Form Designer, select the button (for taking a photo).
>   In the Object Inspector, select the drop-down list for the Action property.
>   Select New Standard Action | Media Library | TTakePhotoFromCameraAction:
>
> On the Events tab, expand the Action node, and then double-click the OnDidFinishTaking event.
>
> Add the following code to the OnDidFinishTaking event handler:
>
> ```
> procedure TForm1.TakePhotoFromCameraAction1DidFinishTaking(Image: TBitmap);
> begin
>   Image1.Bitmap.Assign(Image);
> end;
> ```
>
> This code assigns a picture taken from the mobile device camera to the Bitmap property of the TImage component.

Проверил, что разрешение на работу с камерой стоит (Project | Options | Uses Permissions - Camera). Также я запрашиваю все требуемые разрешения при старте приложения. В Debug и Release поведение одинаковое.

Но .. При клике на кнопку, я получаю ошибку:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference.

Вот мой минимальный код для теста:

```
unit Unit1;
interface
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, System.Permissions,
  FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.MediaLibrary, FMX.Platform, System.Messaging, FMX.Objects,
  System.Actions, FMX.ActnList, FMX.StdActns, FMX.MediaLibrary.Actions,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    ActionList1: TActionList;
    TakePhotoFromCameraAction1: TTakePhotoFromCameraAction;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure PermissionRequestResult(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TArray<string>; const AGrantResults: TArray<TPermissionStatus>);
    procedure DisplayRationale(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TArray<string>; const APostRationaleProc: TProc);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
uses
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
  Androidapi.Helpers,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.JNI.Os,
{$ENDIF}
  FMX.DialogService;

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.PermissionRequestResult(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TArray<string>; const AGrantResults: TArray<TPermissionStatus>);
begin
  // 3 permission involved
  if (Length(AGrantResults) = 3)
  and (AGrantResults[0] = TPermissionStatus.Granted)
  and (AGrantResults[1] = TPermissionStatus.Granted)
  and (AGrantResults[2] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) then
  else
    ShowMessage('Required permission has not been granted') ;
end;

procedure TForm1.DisplayRationale(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TArray<string>; const APostRationaleProc: TProc);
begin
  TDialogService.ShowMessage('Need to access the camera',
    procedure(const AResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      APostRationaleProc;
    end);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  permCam, permRead, permWrite: string;
begin
  // Request permissions
  permCam := JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.CAMERA);
  permRead := JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
  permWrite := JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
  PermissionsService.RequestPermissions([permCam, permRead, permWrite], PermissionRequestResult, DisplayRationale);
end;

end.
```

Как найти и исправить ошибку, как правильно воспользоваться нативной камерой TTakePhotoFromCameraAction?

Comment: Этот же вопрос на Английском: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53829324

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для исправления, нужно установить Project Options > Entitlements List > Secure File Sharing в значение `true`.